# mongo-java-driver 3.2 how to dynamic add the filter builder？

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongo query like this:

```
Bson query = Filters.and(Filters.eq("uid", "123"),Filters.eq("cls", 1));
```

and the other more

```
int type = ??;
if (type != 0) {
    query = Filters.and(
        Filters.eq("uid", "123"),
        Filters.eq("cls", 1),
        Filters.eq("type", type)
    );
}
```

Don't i reset query to dynamic add the filter builder?

Comment: Not clear, but possibly you mean `query = query.and(...` The builders "should" return the modified query instance.

Comment: Thanks. But it can't do this.